# How can I call server relative URLs in a bundled Electron app?

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm trying to call APIs from an Electron app and can't find a way of how to configure this correctly.

First a quick bit of context. The use-case is a web SPA which I would like to offer as a desktop app with minimal changes to the existing codebase. I bundle all the relevant static files produced by webpack into the Electron app (my `main.js` calls `win.loadFile('index.html')`), but then there are calls to APIs for data. In the codebase these are easily-identifiable URLs beginning with "/api/". This works fine when served as a web SPA but fails when packaged into Electron as it assumes it is a call to a static file.

Documentation and existing StackOverflows on the subject is sparse but I have been trying to use interceptHttpProtocol/interceptFileProtocol without much success. My first question would be is this really what I should be using in this case, or is there another mechanism?

If (and that's a big if) I should be using these interceptors, from the documentation I'm don't really understand how they work. If I wish to change a file call to http I understand it would be `protocol.interceptHttpProtocol('file'...)` but I'm not 100% sure. In any case, simply doing:

```
protocol.interceptFileProtocol('file', (request, callback) => {
  callback({ path: request.url.substr(7) });
}
```

(the idea here is to do nothing - recast a file call to the same file call just to test interceptor functionality) results in a blank page and a "Not allowed to load local resource" error. If I set `webSecurity: false` I simply get a blank page and no error. Similar results using interceptHttpProtocol and a link to google.com.

Pointers in the right direction much appreciated.

As plan B I could use Service Workers or Webpack URL rewriting to change the URLs from relative to absolute, but that would be a bit of a hack - surely there is a "proper" way of doing this.

Comment: How the APIs are served?

Comment: REST/JSON. But the main issue here is that they are remote (http/https), while the referrer is part of the Electron bundle (file). Host will differ depending on environment (local, test, preprod, production...) so will be parametrized somehow (shouldn't be a problem).

Comment: you have enable cors in your server if you want to send request from cross origin (includes file protocol also i.e 'index.html' file)

Comment: CORS shouldn't be an issue when calling from a file in Electron, though just in case I added a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header from my local nginx. In any case I'm not at that stage yet - I'm still stuck simply calling a file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, this seems like a better method than using `protocol`:

```
session.defaultSession.webRequest.onBeforeRequest((details, callback) => {
  if (details.url.indexOf('file://api./') == 0) { //TODO Change to regex & parametrize (optional - set default value)
    //TODO Test it works with non-GET (should work - using 307 redirect)
    callback({ redirectURL: `http://localhost/${details.url.substr(12)}` }); //TODO Parametrize (mandatory)
  } else {
    callback({}); //TODO Test this works
  }
});
```

Using `protocol` should still be valid, but I think it would be using `interceptBufferProtocol`:

```
protocol.interceptBufferProtocol('file', (request, result) => {
  if (request.url.indexOf('file://api./') == 0) {
    return result(new Buffer('{}')); //TODO Call API and return Buffer response (I suppose)
  } else {
    // FIXME What goes here!? As in "just continue doing what you would have done"
  }
});
```

I still have no idea how to resolve the FIXME there, so if anybody can answer that it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the path like this

```
path: path.normalize(`${__dirname}/${url}`)
```

Comment: As the above comment says, `__dirname` will give you the current directory in which the electron main process is running and you can load any other path from that relatively. It's common to have a `dist` directory for example. If you're referring to accessing REST APIs then process should be the same as the SPA code.

Comment: Tried this: ```protocol.interceptFileProtocol('file', (request, callback) => { callback({ path: path.normalize(`${__dirname}/${request.url}`) }) })``` and still blank page. Main page is loaded using `win.loadFile('./index.html')`